# How run iPhone simulator without using MonoDevelop?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, monodevelop

How to run the iPhone simulator without using through MonoDevelop?

Comment: Just start it. Seriously, you need to explain your problem in more detail, it doesn't make much sense as it is right now.

Comment: @DarkDust: I think it makes sense, he just wants to start the simulator by itself. Perhaps what doesn't make sense (to me, even) is that he doesn't know how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find iOS Simulator here: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app

Or, just type iOS Simulator in Spotlight.